# Reading files with fixed field length

Tags: matlab, decimal, precision, scanf

I need to read an ASCII data file using MATLAB `fscanf` command. Data is basically floating numbers with fixed field length and precision. In each row of data file there are 10 columns of numeric values and the number of row varies from one file to another one. Below is an example of the first line:

```
0.000  0.000  0.005  0.000  0.010  0.000  0.015  0.000  0.020 -0.000
```

The field width is 7 and precision is 3.

I have tried:

```
x = fscanf(fid,'%7.3f\r\n');
x = fscanf(fid,[repmat('%7.3f',1,10) '\r\n']);
```

but they return nothing!

When I do not specify the field and precision, for example `x = fscanf(fid,'%f');`, it reads all the data but sine some data occupy exactly 7 spaces (example 158.000) it joins the two consecutive numbers which results in a wrong output. Here is an example:

```
0.999158.000
```

it reads this as `0.999158` and `.000`

Any hint or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you get `0.999158.000` from `0.000  0.000  0.005  0.000  0.010  0.000  0.015  0.000  0.020 -0.000`?

Comment: Also what do you mean by the field width is `7` and the precision is `3` in `0.000  0.000  0.005  0.000  0.010  0.000  0.015  0.000  0.020 -0.000`? None of those values have a field width of `7` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data might not be separated by a space (0.999158.000 in the example you made in the question), you could try using `textscan` to read the file.

Notice that with this format you can not have an input such as -158.000.

Nevertheless, with this format, you can not have a value such as -158.000 
Since `textscan` returns a `cellarray` you might need to convert the `cellarray` into a matrix (if you do not like working with `cellarray`).

```
fp=fopen('input_file_5.txt')
x = textscan(fp,repmat('%7.3f',1,10))
fclose(fp)
m=[x{:}]
```

**Input file**

```
  0.999130.000  0.005  0.000  0.010  0.000  0.015  0.000  0.020 -0.000
  0.369-30.000123.005  0.000  0.040  0.000  0.315  0.000  0.020-10.000
```

**Output**

```
m =

Columns 1 through 8

0.9990  130.0000    0.0050         0    0.0100         0    0.0150         0
0.3690  -30.0000  123.0050         0    0.0400         0    0.3150         0

Columns 9 through 10

0.0200         0
0.0200  -10.0000
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. Since I know the exact number of data point I change your suggestion to: x = textscan(fp,'%7.3f',10000). this reads the whole data in one cell. Your hint is really appreciated. I just do not know why textscan and fscanf are different is such a case.

Answer (score 1):

For reading ASCII text files with well defined input as specified in the question you should use the [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function.

```
>> X = dlmread(filename, delimiter);
```

will read numeric data from `filename` that is delimited (along the same row) with `delimiter` into the matrix `X`. For you case you can use

```
>> X = dlmread(filename, ' ');
```

as your data is delimited by a space, `' '`.